# List only unique values in column

Tags: python, list, pandas

I want to filter out repeated values and list only unique values in my DataFrame.

Lets say I have a df like this:

```
     A  B
  0  1  3
  1  2  4
  2  3  3
  3  1  1
  4  3  0
```

And I want to list only the unique values in column 'A'

My desired df

```
 ['2']
```

I tried .drop_duplicates and .unique, but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df[~df['A'].duplicated(keep=False)]
Out[100]: 
   A  B
1  2  4
```

Or, if you want only the column A:

```
df.loc[~df['A'].duplicated(keep=False), 'A']
Out[102]: 
1    2
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

drop_duplicates would also work like this:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A'], keep=False)['A']
Out[105]: 
1    2
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

More compact:

```
df['A'].drop_duplicates(keep=False)
Out[106]: 
1    2
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you. This solves it. It was so simple, but I'm only one week into python and pandas.